# C++ inherit, how to call subclass's method in baseclass's method?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I want to call `B::func2(int x, int y)` in `A::func1(x)`, how to declare them?

```
class A {
public:
    void func1(int x);
    virtual void func2(int x, int y); // do not need implement in A
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void func2(int x, int y) override; // override
};

void A::func1(int x) {
    int y;
    func2(x, y); // I want to use the version of A's subclass
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.func1(x); // call A::func1(x) first then call B::func2(x, y)
}
```

It won't compile, instead the following error message is shown

> > clang++ test.cpp -std=c++11
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "typeinfo for A", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  typeinfo for B in test-bbac7f.o
> ```
>
> "vtable for A", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  A::() in test-bbac7f.o
> ```
>
> NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member >
>   function has no definition.
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Doesn't that already happen with the code you show? How have you tested it? What results do you get, and what results did you expect?

Comment: Why do you want to call `B::func2()` in `A::func1()`?   What do you require if the actual object is not a `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things :

1.) Make `A::func2` pure virtual by appending `=0;`, OR define its body using braces `{}` (note that it can be left empty).

2.) Define the body of `B::func2` using braces `{}` (again, can be left empty).

*You can't call a function which is not defined at first place.*

Answer (score 2):

> `// call A::func1(x) first then call B::func2(x, y)`

It's exactly what will happen in your case. See [at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a86dc5f77f0b1d6d).

Basically, that's what virtual calls are about. Since `func2` is marked "virtual", when it's invoked `A::func1`, the call will go though vtable, hence an overriden method `B::func2` will be called.

It's vice versa: if you want `A::func1` to invoke `A::func2`, you would have to write it explicitly:

```
void A::func1(int x) {
    int y;
    A::func2(x, y); // explicitly tell to use A's version; otherwise the overriden method from the subclass is invoked.
}
```

**P.S.** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45212257/5722863) advises to make `A::func2` pure virtual. This could make sense, if you don't plan to use the implementation of `A::func2`. If, for whatever reason, you need to have some functional code within `A::func2` as well, then typical pattern is to add a call to `A::func2` in a derived class, like this

```
void B::func2(int x, int y) {
  A::func2(x, y);
  // do something specific for B
}
```